# Laravel after login all routes not found

Tags: php, macos, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm working on laravel project and for public user every thing works fine with no issue, but once the user logged all page become inaccessible and I get 404 page not found even for public page. 
 If I delete the cookies public page become accessible again.

This is my login function :

```
 try{
            if (Auth::validate($userdata)) {
                if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
                    // TODO check if is admin Role
                    $user = Auth::user()->getParseUser();
                    if ($user->get('isAdmin'))
                        return Redirect::intended('/');
                    else {
                        Auth::logout(); // logout user
                        return Redirect::back()->with('error', "Access denied");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // if any error send back with message.
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'invalid login parameters ');
            }
        } catch (ParseException  $ex) {
            // if any error send back with message.
            if ($ex->getCode() == 101)
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'invalid login parameters');
            else
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Please contact the admin');
        }
```

Route file :

```
Route::get('/', 'PublicController@index');

Route::get('/product/{id}','PublicController@details');

Route::get('login', 'PublicController@login');
Route::post('login', 'PublicController@loginAction');

Route::get('logout', function(){
    Auth::logout(); // logout user
    return Redirect::to('/');
});


Route::delete('product/{id}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' =>'AnnounceController@destroy']);
Route::delete('product/comment/{id}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' =>'AnnounceController@destroyComment']);
```

Comment: Does your PublicController have implicit middleware?

Comment: Yeah `$this->middleware('guest');` I didn't payed attention to that , removing it fixed my issue thanks. post in seperate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your PublicController.php file for implicit middlewares.

There are only two possible places for middleware:

- routes.php;
- Controllers;

You problem description points in that direction.